# What "ill" does a word in a sentence try to reference?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/democrats-embrace-radical-new-message-government-can-function-210825678.html) there is a line,

> When he was president, Donald Trump passed coronavirus relief measures of his own, including a $900 billion rescue package in December. The new package deviates from its predecessors in large part **because it seeks to address ills that predated the pandemic and will almost certainly outlast it.**

WHat ill did the Trump administration seek? Not COVID-19? I'm not sure about what this sentence tries to mean.(More precisely saying, I don't understand the relationship between the "ill" which "predated" the COVID and the COVID itself).

Sorry for taking time.

Comment: The cited usage doesn't refer to ***any*** specific "ills, issues, problems". They're just ***unspecified*** circumstances that were already around waiting to be dealt with before the pandemic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*ills* means *problems*

> ### [ill](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ill#English)
>
> **(often pluralized) Trouble; distress; misfortune; adversity.**
>
> Music won't solve all the world's ills, but it can make them easier to bear.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I still don't get it. Does this sentence mean Trump tried to seek an illness before the COVID-19 and tired to ignore the COVID?

Comment: @Kentaro The article goes on explaining *"There is money in the new package to significantly reduce child poverty, help Black farmers and increase the number of people who qualify for health care subsidies."* The emphasis the article is making is that Trump's  rescue package was mainly designed to solve virus-related challenges whereas the new package encompasses a more broad range of problems (=ills) including those which emerged before the pandemic and those that "will almost certainly outlast it".

Comment: Ah, "that illness(ses)". Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't say that they sought an ill - they sought to _address_ one (take measures to solve a problem - not necessarily 'an illness').

Comment: IMO, the writer shouldn't have used the word "ill", because it reminds me of the COVID, instead he or she should've used "social and economic problems" etc.

Comment: @Kentaro, the writer wasn't just writing for you, and didn't know that you would read the article and not know the difference between *ills* and *illnesses*.

Comment: Has anyone yet pointed out that the similar meaning words were chosen deliberately *because* of their closeness, as wordplay?

Comment: @RossPresser yes, that's the point. That confused me if I'm allowed to make an excuse.

Answer (score 3):

> What ill did the Trump administration seek?

The Trump administration didn't seek any ill (at least, the writer is not saying so here).

The Trump administration ended on January 20, and the bill being discussed was introduced by the Biden administration (or rather, by their allies in Congress, who are members of the Democratic Party).

Examples of the "ills" being discussed are presented in the sentence immediately following the one you quoted:

> There is money in the new package to significantly reduce child poverty, help Black farmers and increase the number of people who qualify for health care subsidies.

The writer is saying that the bill addresses problems ("ills") like child poverty, economic hardship for Black farmers, and unavailability of health care for poor people. And these problems were present before COVID, and are likely to continue after COVID is gone.

The implication is that the bill is not just addressing COVID, but also other goals of the Democratic party.

Comment: Thanks. The word "ill" confused me. Because the COVID is the illness...

Comment: @Kentaro, An *ill* is not the same as an *illness*. They are two different words with different meanings.

Comment: @ThePhoton To be fair, the words are closely related. When you have an illness, you are ill.

Comment: @Barmar, sure, the terms are related. But there is a reason that *ill* (the noun) is distinguished from *illness* (another noun).

Comment: Of course. But it's also understandable that a a learner would confuse them. The way you responded seemed to deny that understanding.

Comment: @Barmar, maybe I expressed it too bluntly, but it's something anyone learning a foreign language needs to learn: Just because two words sound or are spelled similarly, or even if they have related etymologies, doesn't mean they have the same meaning.

Comment: It doesn't help that in this case the context is related to an actual illness.